# I am trying to connect a radiobutton to a listWidget

Tags: python-3.2

I am not an experienced python programmer at all. 
I am using an application called PyQt4 to create GUI's. 
In this instance, I have to line a radio button (displaying male or female) to a child's name that can be added to a list. 
I have been able to do everything else, except add the radio buttons to the list so that each time a child's name is selected, their gender is displayed.

Please help.

Comment: please include code. What have you tried? What did it do? What did you expect? etc.